# C: scanf for a single char with formatter %s

Tags: c, char, scanf

I see that when I use that code:

```
char c,d;
scanf("%s",&c);
scanf("%s",&d);
printf("%c%c",c,d);
```

seems fix the problem of save ENTER character in **d** variable.

It's a good way or compiler add the string terminator in the memory address next to **c** variable (equals for **d** variable)?

Comment: `%s` is for strings, not single characters.

Comment: @kimiko88 The conversion specifier s is designed to enter a string. So the function scanf appends to the entered characters also the terminating zero character '\0'.

Comment: Use `%c` if you want to read a single character.

Comment: Ok ok, %c is good but to fix "ENTER problem" I can use " %c". Now I understood the problem of using  "%s"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because it will also want to null-terminate the string. In other words, write to `*(d + 1)` (at least!), and that's undefined behavior (namely, overflow).

Answer (score 1):

`%s` expects its argument to point to the first element of an *array* of `char` wide enough to hold the input string *plus* the 0 terminator, so if you want to read a single input character using `%s` then the target must be an array *at least* two elements wide:

```
char c[2];
scanf( "%s", c ); // no & operator since c is an array in this case
```

`%s` tells `scanf` to skip over any leading whitespace, read the next sequence of non-whitespace characters up to (but not including) the next whitespace character, so it will *not* read and store the trailing newline character in `c`<sup>1</sup>.

If you type <kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, then your input stream will contain the sequence `{ ' ', 'A', '\n' }`.  `scanf` will read and discard the leading blank, read `'A'` into `c`, stop reading at `'\n'`, then terminate the string in `c`, so when all is said and done the input stream contains `{ '\n' }` and `c` contains `{ 'A', 0 }`.

`%c` reads and stores individual characters as you've done here. It also does *not* skip whitespace characters, which is why you can store the newline character with it.

Putting everything together, you could do something like this:

```
char c[2], d;
scanf( "%1s", c );
scanf ("%c", &d );
```

which will consume both your input character and the newline.

---

1. For safety's sake, we should use the conversion specifier `%1s` to tell `scanf` to read no more than one character into `c`.